# Элементы массива

Tags: массивы, javascript

Почему-то не выводятся последовательность элементов массива

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function f(obj)
{
var z=new Array()
s=20
for(i=1;i<s;i++){
z.push(i)
obj.s1.value=Z
}
}

</script>
<form name="myform">
<input type="text" name="s1" size="20">
<input type=button name="r"value=" кнопка" 
onclick="f(myform)">
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в `onclick="f(myform)"` аргумент `myform` равен `undefined`. Т.е. его попросту нет.

Answer (score 2):

Не понятно что вы хотите сделать, но если поправить ваш код "Z" -> "z" и другие "мелочи", то получится это — http://jsfiddle.net/hAP5Q/